# Export build parameters into shared library

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is an example of my Jenkinsfile:

```
properties([
   parameters([
       booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'BuildAll', description: ''),
       // lots of params here, some of them are Active Choice Plugin params...
   ])
])

pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage ('Initialize') {
      // code...
    }   
  }
}
```

Now, is it posslible to export those parameters (that are enclosed inside "properties" section) into shared library?

Jenkins shared library: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

I have lots of params and many similar projects and I would like simply to define parameters on one place and include them everywhere (DRY).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create `deriveJobParams.groovy` in `vars` folder with following code in shared library project.

```
def call() {
    properties([
        parameters([
            booleanParam(defaultValue: false, name: 'BuildAll', description: ''),
            [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX',
                description: 'Choose environment category.',
                name: 'ENVIRONMENT',
                script: [
                    $class: 'GroovyScript',
                    script: [sandbox: true, script: 'return ["QA", "DEV", "PROD"]']
                ]
            ]
        ])
    ])
}
```

In job Jenkinsfile, import the share library and call `deriveJobParams()`

```
@Library('my-library@branch or tag') _

// call deriveJobParams at beginning
deriveJobParams()

pipeline {
    
  stages {
  }
}
```